# remove index.php and index.php query string from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm having the following issue:
I have this url www.mysite.com/inde.php?SomePageName
and I want to rewrite it to www.mysite.com/SomePageName
also, I want to get rid of index.php when the url is called without any params eg: mysite.com/index.php or mysite.com/index.php?  should redirect to mysite.com/

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index\.php)?\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Now it's doing a loop because of the last declaration.

Is there any way that I can achieve this ?

Thanks

PS: the whole htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^cumpara-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ index.php?Profile&ID=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^lista-scut-motor-metalic-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ index.php?List&SubID=$3&Categorie=$1&Subcategorie=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^scut-motor-metalic-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ index.php?ViewCat&CatID=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^foto-(.*)-(.*).jpg$ includes/timthumb.php?src=data/$1/$2.jpg&w=300&q=100 [L]
RewriteRule ^product-(.*)-(.*).jpg$ includes/timthumb.php?src=data/$1/$2.jpg&w=530&q=100 [L]
RewriteRule ^side-(.*)-(.*).jpg$ includes/timthumb.php?src=data/$1/$2.jpg&w=175&h=110&q=100 [L]
RewriteRule ^zoom-(.*)-(.*).jpg$ data/$1/$2.jpg [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mysite.com/%1/? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule Despre index.php?Despre [L]
RewriteRule Help index.php?Help [L]
RewriteRule Livrare index.php?Livrare [L]
RewriteRule Contact index.php?Contact [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Answer (score 1):

If it was after me, the simplest solution was to handle the duplicate of index.php via PHP

Having this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

You'll have all REQUEST_URI's written into PHP, so, check if the index.php is present and if it is, then redirect to a non-index.php link :D Like this:

```
if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?") !== FALSE ) {
    $checkq = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $vars = "?".$checkq[1];
    $checkq = $checkq[0]; 
}else { 
    $checkq = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $vars = ''; 
}
if( strpos($checkq, "/") !== FALSE ) {
    $link = explode("/", $checkq);

    if($link[1] == "index.php"){
        unset( $link[1] );
        $link = implode("/",$link);

        header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$link.$vars);
        exit();
        }
}
```

This should work even with you GET variables / your custom .htaccess.